# How can I change the default Mysql connection timeout when connecting through python?

Tags: python, mysql, corpus

I connected to a mysql database using python `con = _mysql.connect('localhost', 'dell-pc', '', 'test')`
The program that I wrote takes a lot of time in full execution i.e. around 10 hours. Actually, I am trying to read distinct words from a corpus. 
After reading was finished there was a timeout error.

I checked Mysql default timeouts which were:

```
+----------------------------+----------+
| Variable_name              | Value    |
+----------------------------+----------+
| connect_timeout            | 10       |
| delayed_insert_timeout     | 300      |
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout   | 50       |
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout | OFF      |
| interactive_timeout        | 28800    |
| lock_wait_timeout          | 31536000 |
| net_read_timeout           | 30       |
| net_write_timeout          | 60       |
| slave_net_timeout          | 3600     |
| wait_timeout               | 28800    |
+----------------------------+----------+
```

How can I change the default timeout ?

Comment: By the way, for those who wish to know how the above table was created, please execute the following query -- 

    SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%timeout';

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Do:

```
con.query('SET GLOBAL connect_timeout=28800')
con.query('SET GLOBAL interactive_timeout=28800')
con.query('SET GLOBAL wait_timeout=28800')
```

Parameter meaning (taken from MySQL Workbench in Navigator: Instance > Options File > Tab "Networking" > Section "Timeout Settings")

- **connect_timeout**: Number of seconds the mysqld server waits for a connect packet before responding with 'Bad handshake'
- **interactive_timeout** Number of seconds the server waits for activity on an interactive connection before closing it
- **wait_timeout** Number of seconds the server waits for activity on a connection before closing it

BTW: 28800 seconds are 8 hours, so for a 10 hour execution time these values should be actually higher.

Comment: Does `gobal` affect all conenctions which connect to db except the current connection?

Comment: Would be nice to know the difference between those three, or at least have a link to the documentation.

Comment: @zhkzyth I had a similar question. This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440336/mysql-wait-timeout Looks like `SET GLOBAL` will set the variable to all active and future connections until the next server restart. There is however a `SET SESSION` that appears to set the variable specific to the current session. There is also https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/set-variable.html for more info.

Comment: @jlh This may help to know the difference between the 3 settings. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html

Comment: I would remove global, so it only affects the current session, usually you don't have privileges to do it with global

Comment: Mentioned further down, but you may also want to "SET global max_execution_time = 60000;" or more

Answer (score 72):

You change default value in MySQL configuration file (option **connect_timeout** in *mysqld* section) -

```
[mysqld]
connect_timeout=100
```

If this file is not accessible for you, then you can set this value using this statement -

```
SET GLOBAL connect_timeout=100;
```

Comment: Note that if you go with the config file method, the mysql client may not reflect the change, but your scripts will!  See my post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9004400/mysql-modification-in-my-cnf-doesnt-take-effect/35186111#35186111

Comment: @dfrankow All values are in seconds.

Answer (score 18):

I know this is an old question but just for the record this can also be done by passing appropriate connection options as arguments to the `_mysql.connect` call. For example,

```
con = _mysql.connect(host='localhost', user='dell-pc', passwd='', db='test',
          connect_timeout=1000)
```

Notice the use of keyword parameters (host, passwd, etc.). They improve the readability of your code.

For detail about different arguments that you can pass to `_mysql.connect`, see [MySQLdb API documentation](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb-1.2.2/public/MySQLdb.connections.Connection-class.html#__init__)

Answer (score 12):

MAX_EXECUTION_TIME is also an important parameter for long running queries.Will work for MySQL 5.7 or later.

Check the current value

```
SELECT @@GLOBAL.MAX_EXECUTION_TIME, @@SESSION.MAX_EXECUTION_TIME;
```

Then set it according to your needs.

```
SET SESSION MAX_EXECUTION_TIME=2000;
SET GLOBAL MAX_EXECUTION_TIME=2000;
```

Comment: How would you do it when you have another query to run ?con.execute(`SELECT  @@SESSION.MAX_EXECUTION_TIME; SET SESSION MAX_EXECUTION_TIME=2000; 
 SELECT * FROM test`) ?

Comment: Note, if the value is `0` that means there is no timeout enabled: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_execution_time