# RMySQL Deadlock work-around

Tags: mysql, r, multiprocessing, database-deadlocks, rmysql

I am running a R-script over multiple cores which inserts data into a table which already holds over 700m rows. Because the table is becoming too large, deadlocks are becoming a common occurrence, even more so since I'm running the same script on multiple cores. I've been trying to work around these deadlocks with TryCatch but to no avail, the script still crashes, making me rerun the script. Is there any function in RMySQL itself to counter deadlocks or does anyone have any advice on a way to work around these deadlocks?

This is the code I was using to try and avoid it but it is in no way pretty (and doesn't work even). It just continues trying to insert the script until it works but the deadlock crashes the script alltogether.

```
   while(done == FALSE){
       dberror = tryCatch({
          dbSendQuery(con, SQLrs)
          done = TRUE
        }, dberror = function(e){
          print("failed, try again")
        })
    }
```

Comment: Can anybody help me with this please?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I am a little late to your problem but I had a similar problem and was able to solve it by adjusting the MySQL timeout in SQL.  I dont think there is anything you can do through RMySQL.  See [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14726789/how-can-i-change-the-default-mysql-connection-timeout-when-connecting-through-py) for how to adjust the MySQL connect_timeout.