# Error while running automysqlbackup

Tags: mysql

I have setup automysqlbackup on centos and have about 52 databases on my db server.

I did try to increase the max_connections to 250 and max_allowed_packet to 100M

But that did not solve the problem.

Looking forward for some help.
Thanks,

When I run automysqlbackup I get the following error:

```
<i>###### WARNING ###### <br>
Errors reported during AutoMySQLBackup execution.. Backup failed<br>
```

> Error log below..
>  mysqldump: Got error: 2013: Lost connection to
>   MySQL server during query when using LOCK TABLES
>  mysqlshow: Can't
>   connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
>  mysqldump: Got error: 2002: Can't
>   connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) when trying to connect
>  mysqldump:
>   Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) when trying to connect
>  mysqldump:
>   Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) when trying to connect
>  mysqldump:
>   Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) when trying to connect
>  mysqldump:
>   Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) when trying to connect
>  mysqldump:
>   Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) when trying to connect
>  mysqldump:
>   Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) when trying to connect
>  mysqldump:
>   Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) when trying to connect
>  mysqldump:
>   Got error: 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query when
>   using LOCK TABLES
>  mysqldump: Got error: 2002: Can't connect to
>   local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (111)
>   when trying to connect

Comment: look like you need to increase the connection timeout , like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14726789/how-can-i-change-the-default-mysql-connection-timeout-when-connecting-through-py

Comment: Let me give it a try with the connection time out.

Comment: I did it did not help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it a specific database it fails on? How far along does it get in the process? Is mysql crashed when the script is finished running or does it just become temporarily unavailable?

Oh, one other thing. Check dmesg and make sure the server has enough ram and mysql isn't being killed by the OOM killer.

Comment: I have about 4GB of RAM and I am unsure about one of the databases that one has about 700+ tables that might cause the script to break I guess.

Comment: Correction it has about 2GB of RAM and I think it was over loaded and then terminated its self

Comment: ah so that is probably your problem then. you may want to exclude that database or just use plain mysqldump + gzip for that database in particular.