# how can i mysql wait_timeout to unlimited

Tags: mysql

I have this config

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES where Variable_name like '%timeout';
+----------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name              | Value |
+----------------------------+-------+
| connect_timeout            | 5     | 
| delayed_insert_timeout     | 300   | 
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout   | 50    | 
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout | OFF   | 
| interactive_timeout        | 28800 | 
| net_read_timeout           | 30    | 
| net_write_timeout          | 60    | 
| slave_net_timeout          | 7200  | 
| table_lock_wait_timeout    | 50    | 
| wait_timeout               | 28800 | 
+----------------------------+-------+
10 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

I needs long time connect, want to unlimited timeout.

Look my php source.

```
<?php
$link = @mysql_connect("localhost","root",$pw);
...
mysql_query($query,$link);
...
// A long time flows (maybe 28,800sec)
mysql_query($query,$link); // error !!
?>
```

Please advise.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I change the default Mysql connection timeout when connecting through python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14726789/how-can-i-change-the-default-mysql-connection-timeout-when-connecting-through-py) (same principle for PHP)

Comment: I already know it, want to unlimited. however i read refer MYSQL. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is **NO**. You can not set the wait_timeout to unlimited.

You can refer MYSQL [wait_timeout](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout)

However if you want to change it then you can try like this:

```
SET GLOBAL connect_timeout=....;
```

Comment: But can he set the timeout to an arbitrarily large number?  If so, then this question is really a duplicate.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen:- Indeed, I went with this line `want to unlimited timeout.` but that would be a different question then...isn't it? Also the present setting shows that the  `wait_timeout               | 28800` which is a good timeout value to have!

Answer (score 2):

There is a limit for wait_timeout. This configuartion value can put in the configuration file my.cnf (for unix)/ my.ini (for windows).

```
Type    Integer
Default Value           28800;
Minimum Value           1;
Maximum Value (Other)   31536000;
Maximum Value (Windows) 2147483
```

Assign wait_timeout in the configuration file within the above range and restart the mysql server.