# Time Out in Deleting data in MySql using MVC Asp.net

Tags: mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-cloud-storage

I have tow table in MySql

**Students**:

```
sCode sName depart
```

**Grades**

```
gID grade sCode
```

I want to delete students and related grades based on Depart parameter.

I'm using Delete Depart Action in my studentContrller:

```
public ActionResult DeleteDepartConfirmd(string Depart)
    {

        var codes = db.students.Where(d => d.Depart == Depart).Select(s => s.sCode);
        var grades = db.grades.Where(s => codes.Contains(s.sCode));
        db.grades.RemoveRange(grades);
        db.SaveChanges();

        var students = db.students.Where(d => d.Depart == Depart);
        db.students.RemoveRange(students);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("studentsByDepart");
    }
```

The problem occourd in first stage in deleting records in Grade table.
The process delete a few records (3-10) records and Time Out happened in browser as it takes a long time.
My question: is my deleting method is the problem? if yes how can I make it better?

The problem occurs in **db.SaveChanges();**

Note: I'm using Google cloud as MySql Host

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing timeout of your mySQL.

Check out this similar thread:
[How can I change the default Mysql connection timeout when connecting through python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14726789/how-can-i-change-the-default-mysql-connection-timeout-when-connecting-through-py)

Comment: Thanks, but I want to delete more than 1000 records. and increasing time will not solve the problem. my be there is a way to bulk deleting.

Comment: Try deleting using foreach loop.
foreach(var agShare in agShares) {
    context.SecurityDataShares.Remove(agShare);
}
context.SaveChanges();