# Node application: How to increase timeout for mysql2 when debbuging?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm using the mysql2 node package (v1.2.0) in a web application and when I'm stepping through the code using the debbugger (using webstorm), if I sit too long at certain breakpoints, initiating the connection will sometimes time out.

Here's the message I receive when it times out:

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at Connection._handleTimeoutError (/Volumes/github-image/bitcoin-core/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:179:13)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:365:14)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:237:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:207:5)
```

I was hoping to increase the timeout to avoid this issue. I tried adding a custom timeout value for when the connection is set up.

```
export const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: dbHost,
  user: dbUser,
  password: dbPassword,
  database: dbName,
  timeout: 60000
});
```

But this had no effect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the timeout is on the client, the property for the connection timeout is `connectTimeout`, not just `timeout`. The [documentation](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#connection-options) for the (compatible) mysql package reads:

> `connectTimeout`: The milliseconds before a timeout occurs during the initial connection to the MySQL server. (Default: `10000`)

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has it's own timeout as well. You can modify it likeso (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14726789/how-can-i-change-the-default-mysql-connection-timeout-when-connecting-through-py))

```
con.query('SET GLOBAL connect_timeout=28800')
con.query('SET GLOBAL wait_timeout=28800')
con.query('SET GLOBAL interactive_timeout=28800')
```