# Connection timed out when no query running

Tags: jasync-sql

I am using vertx.io 3.6.3 and jasync-sql v 1.1.13 for mysql as lib to manage data persistence, The query at QA Env is fine but sometime I receive error message from lib like that :

`{"@timestamp":"2020-07-15T06:36:46.933+00:00","level":"ERROR","logger_name":"com.github.jasync.sql.db.mysql.MySQLConnection","message":"<mysql-connection-14> Transport failure ","throwable_class":"IOException","stack_trace":"java.io.IOException: Connection timed out\n\tat sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)\n\tat sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)\n\tat sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)\n\tat sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)\n\tat sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:377)\n\tat io.netty.buffer.UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:433)\n\tat io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1128)\n\tat io.netty.buffer.SwappedByteBuf.writeBytes(SwappedByteBuf.java:823)\n\tat io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:347)\n\tat io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:148)\n\tat io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:644)\n\tat io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:579)\n\tat io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:496)\n\tat io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:458)\n\tat`

{"@timestamp":"2020-07-15T08:27:06.070+00:00","level":"DEBUG","logger_name":"com.github.jasync.sql.db.mysql.MySQLConnection","message":" - client got disconnected with no running query"}

I checked the mysql server at time exception happend, everything is ok.

Do can you suggest which way to solve it.

Thanks so much.

Comment: did you check connection timeouts on mysql, it might cause this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14726789/how-can-i-change-the-default-mysql-connection-timeout-when-connecting-through-py

Comment: @oshai, Yes I checked it. I am using default configuration, same above

Comment: so maybe it just timeout after the default has reached?

Comment: I think also, but how to ignore this log, ERROR log will trigger something not good. Could you please have some suggestion, I can not edit lib ?

Comment: try to increase the connection timeout to something "infinite".

Comment: You means increase the wait_timeout = infinite ?

Comment: Thanks mate but I dont have permission to change SET @@GLOBAL.wait_timeout=100000.

Comment: That's unfortunate. vertx has it's own pool impl, it has a parameter `connectionReleaseDelay` try to set it to a number lower than the db timeout (it's in millis)

Comment: Thanks @oshai, I already try it today, let wait result :)

Comment: Hi @oshai, Yesterday I meet this exception again. The exception happened after running load test. We run loast test from 10h -> 11h AM but exception timeout happend at 1h PM with no query/update anything. How do you think mate?

Comment: It might be a bug in the pool, or something else I don't know. Try to reduce connectionReleaseDelay to 10000 ms and see if it's better.

Comment: Thanks @oshai mate for quick response ? if I reduce connectionReleaseDelay to 10k ms, did it impact to sql performance ?

Comment: Hi @oshai, did you know why we have this exception : MySQLException","stack_trace":"com.github.jasync.sql.db.mysql.exceptions.MySQLException: Error 1568 - #25001 - Transaction characteristics can't be changed while a transaction is in progress. We already run load test after 1h. Server run 59 minutes ago ok but in the last minutes throw many exception of this

Comment: I think it's better if we discuss this in [gitter](https://gitter.im//jasync-sql/support)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vertx has it's own pool impl, it has a parameter connectionReleaseDelay try to set it to a number lower than the db timeout (it's in millis). Confirm it worked after I set connectionReleaseDelay = 600000 ms