# 'MySQL server has gone away' error from VFP connectivity

Tags: mysql, foxpro

I have a hosting in hostinger.in, When I try to connect with MySQL database from Visual Foxpro 9 SP-2 it is successful, and shows all the data from table but just after 20 seconds it disconnects itself and shows the error: 'Connectivity error: [MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver][mysqlId-5.5.5-10.4.13-MariaDB]MySQL server has gone away.' Any solution for this error?

[image]

Comment: This question a about python with the same problem, it can be used to solve your problem too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14726789/how-can-i-change-the-default-mysql-connection-timeout-when-connecting-through-py

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change the default Mysql connection timeout when connecting through python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14726789/how-can-i-change-the-default-mysql-connection-timeout-when-connecting-through-py)