# How to increase query execution time limit in MySQL

Tags: mysql

We are getting timeout error when we are trying to fetch data which has multiple joins and many calculations in stored procedures.

To improve performance, we definitely need to reduce joins but for now I expect query to give results to web by increasing the timeout limit is it possible or the max time is 30 seconds?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14726789/how-can-i-change-the-default-mysql-connection-timeout-when-connecting-through-py

Comment: Let's see a sample of a slow query.  Please include `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 0):

try running the query from the database or console and see if the **results appear**? and how much execution time?

if the results of the query appear, then the problem is in the application time limit. **try increasing the timeout in the application config**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).